Finding customers who've had multiple tickets within a 3-day period over the last month
I have a table that includes columns for receive_date, customer_id, and ticket_number.  I want to find all the tickets for customers who've had more than 1 ticket created within 3 days of each other.
Tickets Table



row
ticket_number
customer_id
receive_date




1
NY1
0001
2024-10-01


2
NY2
0002
2024-10-01


3
NY3
0001
2024-10-02


4
MD1
0003
2024-10-05


5
NY4
0001
2024-10-06


6
MD2
0003
2024-10-06


7
MD3
0003
2024-10-07



In the above example table, I'd want my query to return rows 1 & 2 for customer 0001, and rows 4, 6, & 7 for customer 3
Query Output



ticket_number
customer_id
receive_date




NY1
0001
2024-10-01


NY3
0001
2024-10-02


MD1
0003
2024-10-05


MD2
0003
2024-10-06


MD3
0003
2024-10-07



I feel like I should be using a Window Function of some kind, but I can't for the life of me figure out what I should be doing with it.  Closest I've gotten is basically just counting all the times the customer_id shows up in the previous month:
SELECT customer_id,
    COUNT(customer_id)
FROM tickets
WHERE EXTRACT(
        YEAR
        FROM receive_date
    ) = YEARNUMBER_OF_CALENDAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -1))
    AND EXTRACT(
        MONTH
        FROM receive_date
    ) = MONTHNUMBER_OF_YEAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -1))
HAVING COUNT(customer_id) > 1
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY COUNT(customer_id) DESC

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

If the next or previous row is within 3 days of the current row it's at least 2 rows.
Untestet:
SELECT *
FROM tickets
QUALIFY
   LAG(receive_date)    -- previous row within 3 days
   OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY receive_date ASC) >= receive_date - 2
OR 
   LEAD(receive_date)   -- next row within 3 days
   OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY receive_date ASC) <= receive_date + 2

